# How to show markers at specified intervals in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have unequally spaced data as shown below:
| x | y |
|:-:|:-:|
| 2 | 10|
| 5 | 11|
| 6 | 10|
| 10| 11|
| 15| 12|
| 19| 10|
| 20| 10|
I want to make a line plot of data with markers using Gnuplot.
By default, markers appear at all points.
However, I need markers only at specific points, say, x = 5, x = 10 and x = 15. Is it possible to get so?

Comment: So, you want to show data points only for x=5,x=10 and x=15 and hide the data for all other x-values? So, basically filtering, what gdupras' answer is suggesting. If it answered your question please mark it as acceptable, otherwise clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have a few points to plot, then the following method works
well enough. The user-defined `filter` function returns `x` if `x`
is 5, 10, or 15. It returns `NaN` otherwise, which is not plotted. The
function makes use of the ternary operator `?:`. See `help ternary`.

```
$DATA << END
| x | y |
|:-:|:-:|
| 2 | 10|
| 5 | 11|
| 6 | 10|
| 10| 11|
| 15| 12|
| 19| 10|
| 20| 10|
END

filter(x) = x == 5 ? x : x == 10 ? x : x == 15 ? x : NaN
plot $DATA using (filter($1)):2 '|%lf |%lf'
```

**Previous answer, before the edit and comment:**
I'm assuming you're talking about the tick marks on the x-axis. You can set their location with `set xtics`.

Since the tick marks you want are evenly spaced, you can specify the start, increment, and end values:

```
set xtics 5, 5, 15
```

If the tick marks are not evenly spaced, you can directly specify their location like this:

```
set xtics (5, 10, 15) # Note the parentheses!
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I am not talking about tick marks on the x-axis. I am talking about the marker which we set and plot using command "set pt 5" and plot using command "plot x:y with points"

Comment: Thanks for the post. The new post almost answered my question. Except that I wanted to a line also with all the data. Hence, I had to plot points and lines separately with same line style using command: `plot $DATA using 1:2 with l ls 1, $DATA using (filter($1)):2 with p ls`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to distribute your data points more equally in the x-range of your plot.

This can be done by changing the x-axis to use a logarithmic scale, e.g.

```
    set logscale x
```

You can also specify the base of the logarithm to match the distribution of your data, for more infos please take a look at the documentation of the logscale command.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I meant something different. I have modified the question now for clarity. Please have a look.